# cannot log in to all account except guest after mounting new partition

Tags: partitioning, login, oracle

In order to do my homework from school, since two days ago, I installed Oracle 11g on my computer running Ubuntu.

While I was installing Oracle 11g, after setting the password for oracle and clicking "next", the installer said that there was not enough space for the `home/oracle` folder,
so to make another space, I mounted another space after checking GParted 
and using Software device management, I mounted it.

Since then, I have not been able to log in to my own administrator account or to the oracle account (which I made for Oracle 11g on Ubuntu): when I type the password for it, it seems to work but it then redisplays the first page to log in, without really logging in.

So I logged in to the guest account, but I cannot even try gnome console manipulation to restore or fix it, because it is the guest account.

Firstly, is there any way I can fix things; Secondly, when oracle said it didn't have enough space for its home folder, what should I have done?

Comment: When you say you "mounted another space", do you mean that you made another partition or what?

Comment: I didn`t, but I found another 'free space' that was written as 'unmounted' and it was /dev/sda5, So using Software device manager, I mounted it with..

Comment: You're going to need to know what's happened to your partitions. I strongly suggest you boot into a live environment to get an accurate picture of what's going on. You'll also be able to fix it from the LiveCD which you won't from a guest login.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>

Log in using your admin account.

Use `usermod -d NEW_HOME` to specify your home directory if it's moved.

I did funny things to my setup and moved my home partition/user, i also needed to chown and chgrp to my home directory to assign it back to my 'new' user

Using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> will hopefully give you enough control over your system to fix it.

Comment: The question suggests they can't login and can only use the guest account. I would assume this stretches to the terminal too.

Comment: I had the same issue he describes. If your home directory is missing or not assigned, the UI will not let you log in. However terminal does not require a home directory.  Try it: create a user (as normal with a home directory), remove the created home directory, logout and try login as the new user...